Deleting segment from polygon and split it into polyline or polyline into two polylines in Leaflet?
What I'm trying to do is have a button to delete a segment from a polygon, or a segment from a polyline. I tried attaching an eventlistenner to each segments I find in the in the drawnItems. I take them layers by layers and then isolate each segments.
When deleting a second segment from a polygon(that is now a polyline) leaflet tries to close the polyline and make it a polygon without deleting the segment that I clicked.


 L.easyButton('fa-regular-eraser-evb', function(btn, map) {
            L.DomUtil.addClass(map._container, 'leaflet-control-delete-active');
            var allTheSegments= drawnItems.getLayers();

            allTheSegments.forEach(function (layer) {
                layer.editing.enable();
                var latlngs = layer.getLatLngs();
                var segments = [];
                var isPolygon = false;

                if (layer instanceof L.Polygon) {
                    latlngs = latlngs[0];
                    isPolygon = true;
                }

                for (var i = 0; i < latlngs.length - 1; i++) {
                    var segment = L.polyline([latlngs[i], latlngs[i + 1]], {}).addTo(map);
                    segments.push(segment);
                }

                if (isPolygon && latlngs.length > 1) {
                    var closingSegment = L.polyline([latlngs[latlngs.length - 1], latlngs[0]], {}).addTo(map);
                    segments.push(closingSegment);
                }

                segments.forEach(function (segment, index) {
                    segment.off('click').on('click', function () {
                        map.removeLayer(segment);
                        map.removeLayer(layer);
                        drawnItems.removeLayer(layer);

                        if (isPolygon && index === latlngs.length - 1) {
                            latlngs.pop();
                        } else {
                            if (latlngs.length > 1) {
                                latlngs.splice(index, 1);
                            }
                        }

                        if (latlngs.length > 1) {
                            var newPolylines = [];
                            var currentPolyline = [];

                            for (var i = 0; i < latlngs.length; i++) {
                                currentPolyline.push(latlngs[i]);


                                if (i === index || i === index + 1) {
                                    if (currentPolyline.length > 1) {
                                        newPolylines.push(currentPolyline);
                                    }
                                    currentPolyline = [latlngs[i]]; // Start a new polyline
                                }
                            }

                            // Add the last polyline if it has more than one point
                            if (currentPolyline.length > 1) {
                                newPolylines.push(currentPolyline);
                            }

                            // Add the resulting polylines to the map
                            newPolylines.forEach(function(coords) {
                                var polyline = new L.Polyline(coords, {}).addTo(map);
                                drawnItems.addLayer(polyline);
                            });
                        }

                        L.DomUtil.removeClass(map._container, 'leaflet-control-delete-active');
                    });
                });
            });
        }, 'Delete a segment').addTo(map);




I didn't go into details why code from question does not work correctly, but rather implemented different algorithm. Basic principles are:

Upon clicking on the delete icon, polygons and lines in drawnItems are split to line segments which are added to saperate segmentLayer layer.
Upon clicking on one of the segments, all points belonging to it's polygon/polyline are iterated and compared to end points of the segment.
If there is no match, point is saved for line creation.
When first match happens, all saved points up to this one are converted to line.
If second match happens right after the first match, segment is skipped and new line started.
Otherwise all points up to this to this one are converted to line.
When iteration is finished, it there are any saved points left, they are converted to line.

Here is complete code of a working example (see JSFiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/TomazicM/g81q7be9/):
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title>Leaflet.draw vector editing handlers</title>
<style>
  body {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
  }
  html, body, #map {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
  }
  .leaflet-control-delete-active > .easy-button-button {
    background-color: gold !important;
  }
</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.draw/1.0.4/leaflet.draw.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet-easybutton@2/src/easy-button.css">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet-src.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.draw/1.0.4/leaflet.draw.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet-easybutton@2/src/easy-button.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="map">
</div>
<script>
  var osmUrl = 'https://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
  osmAttrib = '&copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
  osm = L.tileLayer(osmUrl, {
    maxZoom: 28,
    attribution: osmAttrib
  });
  
  var map = L.map('map').setView([30.194821775512267, 71.47487550973892,], 18).addLayer(osm);
  
  const bldgs = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
      {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {},
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Polygon",
          "coordinates": [
            [
              [
                71.47487550973892,
                30.194821775512267
              ],
              [
                71.4749063551426,
                30.194605015383754
              ],
              [
                71.4752148091793,
                30.19471745251533
              ],
              [
                71.47508069872856,
                30.194905233830244
              ],
              [
                71.47487550973892,
                30.194821775512267
              ]
            ]
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }

  var drawnItems = L.geoJson(bldgs, {
    interactive: false
  }).addTo(map);
  
  var drawControl = new L.Control.Draw({
    draw: {
      polygon: {
        shapeOptions: {
          color: 'red',
          fill: false,
        },
        allowIntersection: false,
        drawError: {
          color: 'orange',
          timeout: 1000
        },
        showArea: true,
        metric: false,
        repeatMode: true,
      }
    },
    edit: {
      featureGroup: drawnItems
    }
  });
  
  map.addControl(drawControl);
  
  map.on(L.Draw.Event.CREATED, function (e) {
    var type = e.layerType,
        layer = e.layer;
    drawnItems.addData(layer.toGeoJSON());
  });

  map.createPane('segments');
  map.getPane('segments').style.zIndex = 1000;
  map.getPane('segments').style.display = 'none';

  const canvasRenderer = L.canvas({
    pane: 'segments',
    tolerance: 3
  });

  var segmentStyle = {
    renderer: canvasRenderer,
    color: "#FF0000",
    weight: 3,
    fill: false
  };
  
  var segmentLayer = L.featureGroup(null, {
    pane: 'segments'
  }).addTo(map);

  var eraseActive = false;
  
  var eraseButton = L.easyButton('fa-eraser', function(btn, map) {
    if (eraseActive) {
      eraseActive = false;
      L.DomUtil.removeClass(eraseButton.getContainer(), 'leaflet-control-delete-active');
      segmentLayer.clearLayers();
      map.getPane('segments').style.display = 'none';
      return;
    }
    eraseActive = true;   
    L.DomUtil.addClass(eraseButton.getContainer(), 'leaflet-control-delete-active');
    map.getPane('segments').style.display = '';

    var allTheSegments = drawnItems.getLayers();
    allTheSegments.forEach(function (layer) {
      var latlngs = layer.getLatLngs();
      var isPolygon = false;

      if (layer instanceof L.Polygon) {
        latlngs = latlngs[0];
        latlngs.push(latlngs[0]);
        isPolygon = true;
      }

      for (var i = 0; i < latlngs.length - 1; i++) {
        L.polyline([latlngs[i], latlngs[i + 1]], segmentStyle).addTo(segmentLayer);
      }

      segmentLayer.eachLayer(function(segment) {
        segment.on('click', function(evt) {
          segmentLayer.clearLayers();
          drawnItems.removeLayer(layer);
          var edges = evt.target.getLatLngs();
          var linePoints = [];
          var wasEdge = false;
          latlngs.forEach(function(latlng, i) {
            if ((latlng == edges[0]) || (latlng == edges[1])) {
              if (wasEdge)
                linePoints[0] = latlng;
              else if (linePoints.length > 0) {
                linePoints.push(latlng);
                var polyline = new L.Polyline(linePoints);
                drawnItems.addLayer(polyline);
                linePoints = [];
                }
              else {
                linePoints[0] = latlng;
              }
              wasEdge = !wasEdge;
              }
            else {
              linePoints.push(latlng);
              wasEdge = false;
            }
          });
          if (linePoints.length > 1) {
            var polyline = new L.Polyline(linePoints);
            drawnItems.addLayer(polyline);
          }
          L.DomUtil.removeClass(eraseButton.getContainer(), 'leaflet-control-delete-active');
          eraseActive = false;
          map.getPane('segments').style.display = 'none';
        });
      });
    });
  }, 'Delete a segment').addTo(map); 

</script>
</body>

</html>


Thanks a lot! This works wonders to delete segments without leaflet trying to close the polygons, the only problem I have now is it seems that it prevents me from using leafletdraw to draw after I removed a line. No js errors. For context I'm in leaflet 1.3.2

Seems that segmentLayer with z-index 1000 catches click events so they don't reach drawnItems layer. See changed code, where map pane with segements layer is now not displayed when delete is not active.

Works perfectly! thanks a lot for the help!

Marked as resolved!
